# Android KSoap Output Error

Tags: android, android-emulator, ksoap

I've tried to work web service on android but I've taken an error in emulator output:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:expecteed: START_TAG 
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope(position:START_TAG@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e567a0)

In here, my code:

```
package com.webServiceDeneme;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*; 

public class WebServiceDenemeActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String NAMESPACE="http://www.vakifbank.com.tr/";
            String METHOD_NAME="faiz-maliyet-oranlari.aspx";
            String SOAP_ACTION="http://www.vakifbank.com.tr/faiz-maliyet-oranlari.aspx";
            String URL="http://192.168.2.1/VipEvents/Services/BasicServices.asmx";
            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            try
            {
                AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive res=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                btn.setText(res.toString());

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                btn.setText(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've received non-SOAP response.

---

To dump and inspect your SOAP request/response, set `aht.debug = true;`, and then after you've called `aht.cal(...)`, print values `aht.requestDump` and `aht.responseDump` to output (like external file or LogCat).

For example:

```
//...
aht.debug = true;
aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Log.e("SOAP_REQUEST", "----------------------------");
Log.e("SOAP_REQUEST", XmlUtils.format(aht.requestDump));
Log.e("SOAP_REQUEST", "----------------------------");

Log.e("SOAP_RESPONSE", "----------------------------");
Log.e("SOAP_RESPONSE", XmlUtils.format(aht.responseDump));
Log.e("SOAP_RESPONSE", "----------------------------");
```

---

Where `XmlUtils` class has next code:

```
public class XmlUtils
{
    static public String format(String unformattedXml)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try
        {
            Document doc = parseXml(unformattedXml);

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");          
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");                

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return unformattedXml;
        }


        return writer.toString();
    }

    private static Document parseXml(String xml) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        return db.parse(is);        
    }

}
```

Comment: i've added your code parts but problem doesn't disappear,there is same error..:(

Comment: This shouldn't fix your problem, it should help you to verify that you receive SOAP response, i.e. Soap Envelope; and not some random response.

Comment: i see..i suppose that i should add propertyinfo part, because this problem is not from web site("www.vakifbank.com.tr" is available)..thanks a lot..